# Search and replace str inside jpg file data by php

Tags: php, jpeg

I want a way to search and replace strings inside `jpg` or `ttf` files by PHP and resave them!

Ttf : change font family name or something

Comment: Please care to show your code

Comment: When i try to use file_get_content() and then str_replace then file_put_content() function it says file is  faild

Comment: Add the code you currently have. As is this is just a code request.

Comment: Best way to get a working Answer : (1) Show an example link to your test jpeg (with "strings inside") so we are talking about same thing. (2) Specify a known existing string to modify. (3) **Show code** of what you've tried so we can help you fix it.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$path = "/home/httpd/html/index.php";
$file = basename($path);         // $file is set to "index.php"
$file = basename($path, ".php"); // $file is set to "index"
```

for an e.g
Let's say you want to replace the file name having index to ttf

```
echo str_replace("index","ttf",$file);
```

You can find and replace according to your needs.

Comment: As I read it OP is trying to replace the contents of an image or font file, not the filename. Also http://php.net/manual/en/function.rename.php would be a better approach for what you've proposed here since the OP wants to `resave them`.

Comment: So you want to rename the file name or the content of the file?

Comment: I want to change the contnent of a binary file not the changing the name of the file!

Comment: Then you need to open the file first, and then search through the whole file and if any occurance is found then it can replaced right?

Comment: @JayminNoob The content in the file isn't present as a human would see it.

Comment: Unfortunately PHP does not hold any functions or properties to convert binary file to human redeable format as they already represent as a string only

Comment: Yea i want to open it and search and replace , can i convert it  to hex ?

Comment: Is there any way we can stop genrating into a binary file?